# How to get current role name in an ansible task

Tags: global-variables, ansible

How can I get the current role name in an ansible task yaml file?

I would like to do something like this

```
---
# role/some-role-name/tasks/main.yml

- name: Create a directory which is called like the current role name
  action: file
          path=/tmp/"{{ role_name }}"
          mode=0755
          state=directory
```

The result of this task should be a directory `/tmp/some-role-name` on the server

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As of **Ansible 2.2**:

`{{role_name}}`

As of **Ansible 2.1**:

`{{role_path|basename}}`

Older versions:

There is no way to do this in the current version of Ansible, here are a couple options that might work for you instead:

1) Use set_fact to set a role_name var to the name the of role as the first task in your tasks/main.yml file

```
- set_fact: role_name=some-role-name
```

2) Pass a parameter to your role that has the name

```
- roles:
  - role: some-role-name
    role_name: some-role-name
```

Comment: this is out of date now just use exactly like the original post

Answer (score 29):

The simplest way is to just use the following

```
{{role_path|basename}}
```

Answer (score 5):

See [this post](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/ansible-project/1471aa9v1x/local-path-to-a-file-within-a-role):

To get the role directory:

```
role_dir: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'pwd') | dirname }}"
```

To get the role name:

```
role_name: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'pwd') | dirname | basename }}"
```

Comment: On ansible 2.1, it gives me the playbook dir, not the role dir

Comment: In Ansible 2.2 role_name and role_path are facts

Answer (score 2):

As of Ansible 2.8 there is `ansible_play_name` which contains the name of the currently executed play.

- https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/48562
- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html

Comment: A play is not a role.