# How can I access ansible variables inside an action plugin (without providing them as arguments)

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I want to write an action plugin (specifically, a variation of 'assert') that logs the role calling the action plugin to file *without* including the role name as an argument to the plugin.

I can see (per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25324261/how-to-get-current-role-name-in-an-ansible-task)) that "{{role_name}}" is a well-defined variable.   But I have no idea how to access it in Python.

I don't want to have to do:

```
- name: example asset
  custom_assert:
     that: 1 > 0
     msg: "Basic maths has broken"
     role: "{{role_name}}"
```

I've tried out the following method (based on the email exchange [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ansible-devel/DQiGednLgU0/JIvQ2Z-zFQAJ))

```
from ansible.inventory.manager import InventoryManager
from ansible import constants as C
inventory = InventoryManager(self._loader, C.DEFAULT_HOST_LIST)
return inventory.get_host(self._connection.host).vars
```

But all that I can access through there is some variables set in my hosts file - not the full range range of variables set with "register" or "setup" or known to ansible for other reasons (such as role_name).

(Additionally, I would like to access the task name as well - although the 'that' and 'msg' arguments nominally include all the info I need, I forsee benefits from being able to log the task name as well):

Comment: I've found a workaround for this specific question - some string operations on `str(self._task)` will give me the role name, but that is a) clunky and b) doesn't explain how to access other variables.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the solution provided under [Custom Ansible Callback not receiving group_vars/host_vars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51640444/custom-ansible-callback-not-receiving-group-vars-host-vars) is what you are looking for.

Basically, you need to access the play variable manager as follows:

```
def v2_playbook_on_play_start(self, play):
variable_manager = play.get_variable_manager()
hostvars = variable_manager.get_vars()['hostvars']
```